# So That vs. Consequently

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know that "so" has many different meanings, so in the following context, which is the correct answer and why? I think it is (a) or (b); it just feels like they are both correct.

> He suffered severe injuries; [Your Choice], he made a complete recovery.
>
> - (a) so that
> - (b) consequently
> - (c) unless
> - (d) nevertheless

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome on English Language Stack Exchange! There is a verb missing between "He" and "severe injuries", e.g. "He suffered severe injuries". If "suffered" is the verb you meant, please add it.

Comment: You need to consider the precise meaning of each word and see if it fits in the sentence.

Comment: @HussainBiedouh I’m going to migrate your questions over to [ell.se] where you can get an answer from people who better understand your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Both "**so**" and "**consequently**" can be used to introduce the result or the effect of something else. In the example sentence, the recovery is not the result or the effect of the injuries, so "so", "so that" or "consequently" cannot be used here.

"**Unless**" essentially means "if ... not". For example, "You won't pass the test, unless you work harder." Or, "He will recover quickly from his injuries, unless there are unexpected complications." "Unless" is not a good fit for the example sentence.

"**Nevertheless**" is a rather formal word that can mean "in spite of ..." or "however". You could say, "He suffered severe injuries; **nevertheless**, he made a complete recovery." This would have the same meaning as, "**In spite of his** severe injuries, he made a complete recovery."

So (d) is the only valid option in your example sentence.